# How to give multiple arguments to find element by css selector

Tags: c#, css-selectors, selenium-webdriver

Hi I'm kind of new to selenium, so please bear with me if the question is too basic.
I wanna access a date picker element and choose a specific date.
I am trying to access the span element using both class and text inside.
I get an error of invalid string. Is the syntax below correct?

```
_driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span[class='xxx'][contains(text(),'xx')]"))
```

Comment: I think contains() is deprecated...edit: yes it is, read: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#content-selectors

Comment: If you could post here your HTML element, then we could provide the exact CSS selector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at this cheatsheet

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/

I think it might be more like

```
_driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span.CCC:contains('TTT')"));
```

where `CCC` is your class name and `TTT` is the text your looking for.